# General error: 3780 Referencing column 'post_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_post' are incompatible

Tags: php, mysql

I've been stuck on this error for several days. I can't seem to find the error to correct the problem. A charitable soul could help me plz ?

i got this error :

> General error: 3780 Referencing column 'post_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_post' are incompatible.

```
    <?php
require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';

require dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'DataPDO.php';
use Config\Connection;

$pdo = new Connection();

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE users (

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ft_image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role ENUM ('Author', 'Admin', 'Subscriber') NULL DEFAULT 'Subscriber',
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table users succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE posts (

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ft_image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    published TINYINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table posts succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE comments (

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    pseudo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    published TINYINT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table comments succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE categories (

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ft_image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table categories succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE posts_comments (

    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    comment_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, comment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_post
        FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
        REFERENCES posts (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_comment
        FOREIGN KEY (comment_id)
        REFERENCES comments (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table posts_comments succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE users_posts (

    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_post
        FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
        REFERENCES posts (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table users_posts succesfully !';

$pdo->getPDO()->exec("CREATE TABLE posts_categories (

    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, category_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_post
        FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
        REFERENCES posts (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_category
        FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES categories (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4");

echo 'Created table posts_categories succesfully !';
```

Answer (score 2):

id in the table Posts is

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

post_id in posts_categories is

```
post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

Here the part "unsigned" creates your problem
Make both Unsigned, or leave it out

Comment: I have already tried it works but another error appears. General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'fk_post' . I am in training and I saw this code work correctly in the tutorial video but at home it does not work. Link tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyVccRErcYc&t=1672s

Comment: you add a FK named fk_post to multiple tables. Use unique names. Or better maybe: use a tool (heidisql, navicat or phpmyadmin) to create your tables and relations between them. (and let the tool choose a (unique) name for the FK relations